# Agile web development with Ruby on Rails: how does the view have access to this instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, instance-variables

In chapter 9 of Agile Web development with Rails 4

You have a model cart.rb which has many line items

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

You also have a line items model

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

in controllers/concerns you define a module current cart

```
module CurrentCart
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern    
    private    
      def set_cart
        @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
            @cart = Cart.create
            session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
        end
      end
```

When you add a line item, you call the create method of line_items_controller.  Before create method is called, it calls the set_cart method of the current cart module by such

```
before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
```

After line item is posted, it redirects the page to the cart index page as such

```
format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
```

When the view is displayed, it uses

```
  <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
    <li><%= item.product.title %></li>
  <% end %>
```

My question is how does this view have access to @cart instance variable which is defined in the current_cart module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really using the module to know the instance variable.
The last thing your code did was to redirect to @line_item.cart which is the show  action in the CartsController.

So you have a show action, that has an instance variable @cart so it can be used in the views.

Or if you do not have a show action, then rails is smart enough to make a show action from the redirect url. and know to make an instance variable @cart using the url id.

Comment: oh i get it.  it uses this:  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]  which has instance variable @cart.  thanks

Comment: this is how set_cart in carts_controller is implemented:
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
in the redirect url, there is no parameter being passed as id?  when it is invoked.  then how is set_cart able to retrieve the id?

Comment: In the     redirect_to @line_item.cart     there is an id being passed, that redirect creates the url /carts/:id so there is an id

Comment: is it because, when you redirect to show action u do it using @line_item.cart and rails is able to extract the id itself from it?

Comment: exactly, Rails is smart enough to extract the id and create the instance variable.